# Magento: PNG Watermark with white borders

Tags: magento, png, watermark

When I add the watermark to the images, I've this strange problem. The Png file has white border, like a line of white pixels around my logo. I tryed also a Jpeg file with white rectangular border without trasparent, but the white has irregular pixels hole, without any sense. I see something similar in a kind of bug of previous versions of magento like the 1.3, but I think it has been solved... I Search online for a few days but no solution founded about that. Can you help me to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is Image Aspect Ratio Issue,
the images are not fitting to your store image size

```
<?php 
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')
    ->constrainOnly(false)
    ->keepAspectRatio(true)
    ->keepFrame(true)
    ->resize(160, 210);
?>
```

Try to adjust the image sizes or crop the images.